# Buying tokens from a smart contract that receives BNB from another smart contract

Tags: solidity, tokens, binance-smart-chain

I'm trying to develop a smart contract that will receive BNB directly from a token contract and then use this to buy tokens from the BNB it has received.

But everything I try seems to cause issues and I'm not quite sure why, or where the issue lies?

The token contract uses the following function to send BNB

```
function transferToAddress(address payable recipient, uint256 amount) private {
        recipient.transfer(amount);
}
```

This function works and I receive the BNB in both the smart contract and personal wallets, but when I add the following code to a new smart contract it fails, but only fails when the token contract sends the BNB.

If I send the smart contract BNB directly it works and purchases the tokens through the router, but when the token contract calls the `transferToAddress` function and sends BNB to the new smart contract it fails.

```
receive() external payable {
    buyTokens(msg.value);
}

function buyTokens(uint256 _amount) private {
    address[] memory path;
    path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = WBNB;
    path[1] = TOKEN;

    // call the router swap
    router.swapExactETHForTokens{ value: _amount }(
        0, 
        path, 
        address(this), 
        block.timestamp
    );
}
```

The transaction cannot succeed due to error: undefined. This is probably an issue with one of the tokens you are swapping.

I have added a bool to enable/disable the buying and when this is disabled, everything works as it should and the smart contract receives the BNB from the token - but as soon as its enabled it shows the same error?